# How to display all images from NSDocument directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, alassetslibrary, nsdocumentdirectory

First i selected images from photo library to ALAsset Library and after that i stored images in document directory from ALAsset library path.

i am using this code to store images in document directory from ALAsset Library.... Its working perfect... Now i want to display all images which are stored in document directory in table view.. how  can i do this???
can anybody help me??

**Code for importing images from ALAsset Library to NSdocument directory**

```
for (int j=0; j<[assetArray count]; j++) {

ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [[assetArray objectAtIndex:j] defaultRepresentation];
NSString* filename = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[representation filename]];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filename contents:nil attributes:nil];
NSOutputStream *outPutStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filename append:YES];
[outPutStream open];

long long offset = 0;
long long bytesRead = 0;

NSError *error;
uint8_t * buffer = malloc(131072);
while (offset<[representation size] && [outPutStream hasSpaceAvailable]) {
    bytesRead = [representation getBytes:buffer fromOffset:offset length:131072 error:&error];
    [outPutStream write:buffer maxLength:bytesRead];
    offset = offset+bytesRead;
}
[outPutStream close];
free(buffer);
```

}

After that i got the contents of directory using this code:

```
 NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
fileList = [manager directoryContentsAtPath:newDir];
```

Its also working... but now when i want to display images from document directory. It doesn't show anything....

```
 setImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Can anybody help, where is the problem?????
 - I have one doubt:
  *Is it the right way to import images from ALAsset Library to document directory???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**This answer is about how to retrieve images from documents directory and displaying them to UITableView...**..

first of all you have to get all images from your documents directory to an array....

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    arrayOfImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSError *error = nil;


    NSString *stringPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath: stringPath  error:&error];

  for(int i=0;i<[filePathsArray count];i++)
  {
      NSString *strFilePath = [filePathsArray objectAtIndex:i];
      if ([[strFilePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || [[strFilePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"png"] || [[strFilePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"PNG"]) 
      {
         NSString *imagePath = [[stringPath stringByAppendingString:@"/"] stringByAppendingString:strFilePath];
         NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
        if(data)
        {
          UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
          [arrayOfImages addObject:image];
        }
      }

  }

}
```

after that - using this array you can show the image in uitableview cell
remember dont add the table view on your view untill your array is fill.....

```
#pragma mark - UItableViewDelegate methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrayOfImages count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tablView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    //adjust your imageview frame according to you
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 470.0, 80.0)];

    [imageView setImage:[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    return cell;
```

}

Now run it will work ..

Comment: In above  data=(null)..... before data its working... but after this      NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:strFilePath];   its not working... :(

Comment: please NSLog(@"%@",strFilePath); after NSString *strFilePath = [filePathsArray objectAtIndex:i]; and see what comes ..... and tell me

Comment: It display    strFilePath=IMG_0034.PNG

Comment: i changed this  line    **if([[strFilePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"PNG"])** and now when i write this **NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:strFilePath];
            NSLog(@"data=%@",data);**  it display **data=(null)**

Comment: oh ...IMG_0034.PNG problem is with if condition [[strFilePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"PNG"] ...... dont compare it with jpg extension ..

Comment: i have edited my answer now check it.... you got NSData null because IMG_0034.PNG this is PNG not jpg ....... and there is no image with name IMG_0034.jpg ...

Comment: code for importing images from ALAsset Library to document directory is right?????

Comment: No -  code is for displaying image from documents directory to UITableView .... this is not about ALAssetLibrary...what do you want @Rox - ?

Comment: what is your email id ..... i send you a sample code how to retrieve images from phone library using ALAssetLibrary then save these to document directory .... both are different steps...first import all images ....

Comment: "Code for importing images from ALAsset Library to NSdocument directory" .... these are two question! ok now i got you wait i give you a tutorial .....

Comment: Thanx Vakul..... i was asking about my code... which i used for importing images from ALAsset library to document directory....

Comment: I selected multiple images from Photo library to document directory using ALAsset Library.... now i want to display them.. but it didn't work.....

Comment: why are you saying again and again "importing images from ALAsset library to document directory" .... first achieve your first step... read how to import all images from phone library using ALAssetLibrary.... then go to for next step .. :-)

Comment: my email id is rakesh@click-labs.com

Comment: and one more thing what do you want to select one by one, multiple, or all images from phone lib ?

Comment: i already imported images into my document directory..... my problem is how to display that images???? hope u got my problem

Comment: are you sure you have imported all images from phone lib?.... and why are you saving them to NSDocumentDirectory if you want to show them on UITableView ?

Comment: You already have an assetsArray ... you can show images from here

Comment: i want to store all selected images in my personal document directory...  i want to retrieve them from my document directory not from photo library....

Comment: then my code should work - my code is for how to pick images from documents directory and show them to UITableView ..... what is the problem ?

Comment: can u mail me the sample code how to retrieve images from phone library using ALAssetLibrary then save these to document directory

Comment: now try my edit answer it will work .... i have edit before  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]; line ....

Comment: Awesome dude...... its working now........ thanku thanku thanku... thanx a lot man....

Comment: hey thanx dude... can u tell me plz how can i display four images in one row instead of one image???

Comment: first of all please dont chat .... this is ban on this site ... and if you have problem you can ask another question ... sorry i can not reply in chat .... :-(

Comment: ok dude... i will ask this in another question... thanx for the help.. and in future.....

Comment: the codes won't even compile. At least `documentsDirectory` is not defined. Double check codes.

Comment: @Raptor - Thanks! Actually `stringPath` is `documentsDirectory` it was copy paste error. Now corrected.

Comment: And since iOS SDK upgrades, `stringByAppendingFormat:` will now generate warning. Recommend to replace it with `stringByAppendingString:`

Comment: @Raptor Okay Done! Actually it is very common thing developers always be updated. And never forget to check the posted date of any answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can directly get contents by this :

```
NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject] error:NULL];
```

To set Image :

```
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:"Your complete path"]];
```

Comment: thanx for the reply....... i got the contents but it doesn't display image in image view....why???

Comment: NSArray *fileList = [manager directoryContentsAtPath:newDir];  setImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[fileList objectAtIndex:0]];   I m using this code...

Comment: setImage.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imgFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; Do like this in the last line...

Comment: If you are using it in table view,just edit your code as : 
`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[yourImageView setImage :[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[fileList objectAtIndex:Indexpath.row]];`

Comment: Short and simple solution.Worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the image files from the Document Directory this way:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
    NSMutableArray *imgFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<filePathsArray.count; i++) {
        NSString *strFilePath = [filePathsArray objectAtIndex:0];
        if ([[strFilePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"jpg"]) {
            [imgFiles addObject:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"array with paths of image files in the Document Directory %@", filePathsArray);
```

And then you can display the images into the `UITableView` like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 50, 50)];
    img.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imgFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [cell addSubview:img];

    return cell;
}
```

Cheers!!!

Comment: thanx for the replyI got the all images in array. but when i used this path to display images in image view, it doesn't display any image... i don't know why????

Comment: Sorry it didn't work.... imgfiles have contents but it is not displaying in UIImageView....