# How can i display images from document directory to image view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uiimageview

I want to display my images from document directory... i got the contents of directory.
but when i want to display image, it display nothing... I checked in document directory..
there are images.. but don't know why it is not displaying in UIimage view???

can anybody help me??? where is the problem???

MY code

```
NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:newDir  error:nil];
setImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Hey i got the answer..... Please follow this link

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11294125/1465480)

Thanx to everyone for their precious help........

Comment: all the image in the NSDocumentDirectory?

Comment: what are you passing in newDir ?

Comment: @ Kobe.o4    Yes all images are in document directory...

Comment: @Jennis   newDir is the NSString in which i m passing the path of directory where the images are stored

Comment: Make sure newDir value is not nil. Rest code is working fine.

Comment: Yes, I sure newDir value is not nil.. bcoz i checked it with NSLog...

Comment: Than make sure there is file under that directory because I put your code in new project and it is working fine :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing `UIImage` with `UIImageView`. After creating your `UIImage` setImage, you need to set it to a UIImageView:

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:setImage];
```

then you need to add the myImageView to your view:

```
[self.view addSubview:myImageView];
```

**EDIT**:

to check for if the file exists at a path you use `fileExistsAtPath` and log the output:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath]) {

     NSLog(@"file exists!");
}
```

myPath would be the NSString for the path you are obtaining. I think most likely that you are not getting the path to the file correctly. Are you sure the images are in the documents directory? if you are using the simulator you can always use finder to locate the files and folders inside your app's sandbox. try to look your images up manually by going to

```
 ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/x.x/Applications/
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanx for the reply.....  i m using storyboard and setImage is UIimage view, which i already defined...

Comment: ok.. hmm maybe you need to double check the path of the image.. try using `[[NSFileManager sharedManager] fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:NO]` to test it.

Comment: hey KDaker thanx for the help....  i got my solution... and updated my question...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code..

```
NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );

NSString *docDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *imagePath=[docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"your image-name"];

UIImageView *myimage=[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
myimage.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]];    
[self.view addSubView:myimage];
[myimage release];
```

may this will help you...

Comment: please check your image in document directory and copy the path and check it is giving you the correct image or not... have you saved this image with correct extension .. ?

Answer (score 0):

If your image in the document directory use following:

```
NSString *directory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *newPath = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myMovie.m3u8"];
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:newPath];
```

Comment: Get the NSData from that path.and then set image with NSData .

Comment: Try this:NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:newPath] Just check whether the data is coming or not?

Answer (score 0):

You have used path for document directory but not provided path for image stored there.. check following here

```
NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:newDir  error:nil];
setImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/imageName.png", [filePathsArray objectAtIndex:0]]];
```

Comment: check the path that is re turned by: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/imageName.png", [filePathsArray objectAtIndex:0]]` is it the same path your image stored?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:newDir  error:nil];
NSString *str_imgpath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/imageName.png", [filePathsArray objectAtIndex:0]]
imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:str_imgpath]];
```