# how to use nsdocuments directory for downloads in iphone

Tags: iphone

I have an iphone app with downloads option  and iam using nsdocument directory path for downloading.but after the download how can i get to access the documents path in iphone. Do i need to install any other app for file access . if Yes, Please tell me the app.Thank you .

Comment: You want to download and save in document directory?

Comment: So you know the document path as you are downloading into it, but you don't know the document path in order to access the files within it? I'm confused.

Comment: You need to use the same path for accessing the data which you used for downloading the data in document directory.

Answer (score 0):

//NSDownloadsDirectory = For Download folder

//NSDocumentDirectory = For Document folder

```
    NSArray *pathArr = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDownloadsDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *downloadsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

```
Store the content to this path(you can create a folder in it too.). And also fetch the files stored in this folder, by enumerating to the files in this directory
```

Comment: YES, But how to access the directory from iphone and not from code

Comment: You can't. iOS does nto allow file system access. All files are stored with the apps sandbox. Other apps can't access the file.

Comment: @rckoenes is right. You cannot access the File system likewise Android SD Card. But with URL Scheme options you can open the downloaded files in your App Please check http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/

Answer (score 0):

[How to display all images from NSDocument directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293690/how-to-display-all-images-from-nsdocument-directory?rq=1) check this link and if you want access the app file than check this download it
http://download.cnet.com/iExplorer/3000-2141_4-10969335.html

Answer (score 0):

You can access the folder using `iExplorer` application on Mac OS X. You can also access it through `Xcode` on your test device by doing this:

Go to `Xcode > Window > Organizer > Devices`

On the window, select the app you want to check and you can see the directories:

[image]

**You can download the whole directory to access the items in it.**